# Do python functions care whether or not you use their output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm using urllib2 to send GET and POST requests to a server with parameters, but for some of the requests I don't need to know the server's response besides the fact that it's not a 404, and urlopen throws an exception on 404s. However, if I just use the line:

```
urllib2.urlopen(address, params)
```

The server does not see the request. It's as if it just never gets sent. However, if I then do

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(address, params)
```

the command goes through. I looked at the source for urllib2 and found the function for urlopen, which looks like this:

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
    ...
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
```

It seems like that `_opener.open` function is not being run when I don't store the output of urlopen. Does python just not execute the return statement if I don't ask for the function's output?

Comment: As the assignment of the return value happens *after* the function was executed, it’s impossible for the function to know whether its return value is being assigned to something. As Martijn said, your error is elsewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This isn't entirely true, there are many function that use yield, and will not do anything meaningful unless you do something with it.

Comment: @Soviero: Those are generator functions. They **do** return something, a generator object. `urlopen()` is no generator function, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup.  But I doubt the OP would make that distinction.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know that *his* function was not a generator, just pointing out an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a function's behaviour does not alter based on wether or not you store a reference to the return value or simply ignore it. The function is executed *before the return value is stored or ignored*. If a function call results in an exception being raised, there is no return value at all, even.

Your analysis of what happens is incorrect, the problem lies elsewhere.

You could easily have tested this yourself though:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print "foo() called"
... 
>>> def bar():
...     return foo()
... 
>>> bar()
foo() called
>>> result = bar()
foo() called
```

or, using `urllib2.urlopen()` itself, using `http://httpbin.org/status/404` to trigger a 404 Not Found response:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND
```

Both actions raise an exception.

Comment: That test is not really helpful, as there could be (theoretically) special inspection methods that tell you whether the return value is stored or not.

Comment: @poke: you could use `__del__` to detect if the reference count dropped to 0, sure. However, Python as a language does not 'optimize' by not executing the `return` expression when the caller is going to discard the return object.

Comment: I obviously know that it’s not possible. My point is that—as I said—theoretically there could be something; and without knowing that, you can’t really write an example that tests whether it works or not.

Comment: @poke: you mean the OP could not have been assured their hypothesis is wrong even if a simple experiment would have shown them otherwise?

Comment: No, I mean that there could be some hypothetical `abortFunctionIfReturnValueIsDiscarded` statement somewhere inside the `urlopen` implementation that does exactly what OP thought would happen. Now if you don’t know about that statement, you can’t test it.

Answer (score 0):

Python will always execute the return statement regardless of whether or not you utilize the return value